# LINQ: Error converting HashSet<Dictionary<String, String>> to Dictionary<String, HashSet<Dictionary<String, String>>>

Tags: c#, linq

I have created my custom class to manage a dictionary of multiple values against a key:

```
public sealed class MultiDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, HashSet<TValue>>
{
    // Class implementation
}
```

I am using it in a code, like this:

```
HashSet<Dictionary<String, String>> myHashSet; // Fill in values
MultiDictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>> myDictionary = myHashSet
    .GroupBy(row => row["ID"])
    .ToDictionary(var => var.Key, var => var.ToHashSet());
```

However, when I compile that code, I get following error. I must be missing something very simple, but to me it appears that both the types (converting from and converting to) look same.

```
Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>>>' to
'MultiDictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>>'.
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Interestingly enough, if I change my code to as follows the error goes away:

```
HashSet<Dictionary<String, String>> myHashSet; // Fill in values
Dictionary<String, HashSet<Dictionary<String, String>>> myDictionary = myHashSet
    .GroupBy(row => row["ID"])
    .ToDictionary(var => var.Key, var => var.ToHashSet());
```

What's wrong in my original code?

Comment: There is nothing interesting about it. In the first one you're trying to put a hashset into `Dictionary<String, String>`  and the compiler is saying you can't. Having said that, I would create a class that more closely resembles the needs so you have to read hashset, dictionary of this and that. What exactly is this for?

Comment: @CodingYoshi: No, in the first one I am **not** trying to put a `HashSet` into `Dictionary<String, String>`.... I am trying to put a `HashSet` as a value into into `MultiDictionary`

Comment: You don't need to reinvent [the wheel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2).

Comment: Yes you're trying. You say "I am trying to put a HashSet as a value into into MultiDictionary", you have defined the value as `Dictionary<String, String>` so you are trying.

Comment: @CodingYoshi: What I meant to say was that - I am putting `HashSet<Dictionary<String, String>>` as a value into a `MultiDictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>` which is same as `Dictionary<String, HashSet<Dictionary<String, String>>>`. So essentially I am putting `HashSet<Dictionary<String, String>>` as a value into a `Dictionary<String, HashSet<Dictionary<String, String>>>`. However, the answer by @AdamLopes make sense. I have extensive C++ background, so I was thinking with C++ mindset!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to implicitly cast a more abstract type to a less abstract type.

By inheriting from `Dictionary<TKey, HashSet<TValue>>` you have created a specialization which is not directly assignable from the type it inherits from.

The simplest answer would be to use composition rather than inheritance and have your 'MultiDictionary' contain a `Dictionary<TKey, HashSet<TValue>>`

This would allow you to define a constructor which accepted the `Dictionary<TKey, HashSet<TValue>>` and assign it to a member variable.

It would also allow you to use the implicit conversion operator (not something I particularly recommend, as it is a lesser used feature of the language and can be confusing to maintenance programmers in the future, however for your above code to compile, you would need to remove the inheritance relationship between your 'MultiDictionary' and `Dictionary<TKey, HashSet<TValue>>`

and add the following methods to your 'MultiDictionary' class

```
public static implicit operator MultiDictionary<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, HashSet<TValue>> d)
{
    return new MultiDictionary<TKey, TValue>(d);
}


public static implicit operator Dictionary<TKey, HashSet<TValue>> (MultiDictionary<TKey, TValue> md)
{
    return md.m_dictionaryOfHashSets;
}
```

Unlike languages such as C++ where you can do nasty things relying on the fact that the memory layout of two classes are identical, C# does not permit this. 
What value does your MultiDictionary class add over the Dictionary of HashSets anyhow? Could you perhaps provide this functionality with extension methods instead?

Comment: If you were going to adopt this approach, it would probably be a little nicer to refactor the code to put the linq query which extracts the "ID" from the hashset into your MultiDictionary class, as it would then encapsulate this implementation detail of the MultiDictionary class within it, rather than having it be a bit of external boilerplate that consumers of this class just need to "know". Also, raising a meaningful exception telling consumers that they need to have a key of "ID" in the enclosing dictionary would be more informative than the generic linq exception that is thrown by default

Comment: Current implementation of MultiDictionary is used extensively in my project. So rather than changing that implementation to use composition rather than inheritance, I just looped over myHashSet and built myDictionary by adding the key and value.